# Heroku cannot find Go application

Tags: heroku, go

I'm having some trouble getting it detect the application binary.

For example, my project is called GoServer which is located in `$GOPATH/src/GoServer` and its binary (which was created by running `go install` in the project directory) is located in `$GOPATH/bin/`

Now if I try to run the instance locally using `go run main.go` it works just fine. If I run it locally using the Heroku Local toolkit (`heroku local`) it also works fine. BUT when it push to Heroku's remote repo and open the page from there, it crashes. In the logs it says that it could not find GoServer (`bash: GoServer: command not found`).

How can I fix this? Most of the similar issues threads I've seen refer to a misconfigured `GOPATH` but mine seems to be fine since Heroku Local works, but not the actual remote setup.

Comment: This binary exists in your `$GOPAHT/bin` locally, but most likely a fresh build / install process does not produces is, so it will not be found on heroku. If you need help, we need to know what repo you deploy and what's your heroku config.

Comment: @icza It's a bare minimum codebase that I was using to learn Go. Here's more info: https://gist.github.com/najmsheikh/a46b7de388d1a798aa8b7c3dfa1bbdba

Comment: The package in your `glide.yaml` is incorrect. Rename `GoServer` to `goserver` (lowercaed) and change package in first line of `glide.yaml` to: `package: goserver`. And then use `goserver` in the `Procfile` too.

Comment: That fixed it! Though I did have to keep the capitalizations. You can submit the answer below so you can get credit for it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package in your `glide.yaml` is incorrect, change it to the package your code is in, that is `GoServer`. This is the package that gets installed by glide. Since this did not match the package (folder) of your code, `GoServer` did not get installed and was not available as an executable on heroku. It worked for you locally as you (or your IDE) compiled and installed `GoServer` and placed the executable into `$GOPATH/bin`, and so it could be run locally.

So the first line in `glide.yaml` should be:

```
package: GoServer
```